# Matomo formerly Piwik API.getBulkRequest returns empty list

Tags: python, python-requests, matomo

Its really strange:
API.getBulkRequest is not working with python-requests

it works fine if i try the same in the browser.

If i try to do any other matomo request in python it works fine.

Here is my code:

For urls i just used the sample from Matomo reporting API reference.

```
import requests

urls = [
    'method%3dVisitsSummary.get%26idSite%3d1%26date%3d2012-03-06%26period%3dday',
    'method%3dVisitorInterest.getNumberOfVisitsPerVisitDuration%26idSite%3d1%26date%3d2012-03-06%26period%3dday']
params = {
    'method': 'API.getBulkRequest',
    'urls': urls,
    'format': 'json',
    'module': 'API',
    'token_auth': MATOMO_SECRECT_TOKEN,
}
r = requests.post(api_url, params)
print(r)
print(r.json())

Result:
<Response [200]>
[]
```

Can anyone see the obvious mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does work:

```
import requests

api_url="https://demo.matomo.org/"

params = {
    'method': 'API.getBulkRequest',
    'urls[0]': 'method%3dVisitsSummary.get%26idSite%3d3%26date%3d2012-03-06%26period%3dday',
    'urls[1]': 'method%3dVisitorInterest.getNumberOfVisitsPerVisitDuration%26idSite%3d3%26date%3d2012-03-06%26period%3dday',
    'format': 'json',
    'module': 'API',
    'token_auth': "anonymous",
}
r = requests.post(api_url, params)
print(r)
print(r.json())
```

The `&urls[0]=test&urls[1]=test` is a bit special to PHP and requests doesn't automatically generate such a structure.

You could add the parameters like that:

```
for index, url in enumerate(urls):
  params["urls[{count}]".format(count=index)] = url
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much!!